# "In which" or "of which"?

Tags: grammaticality, syntactic-analysis, in-of

I was writing the following sentence and became lost in thought. I wasn't sure whether to use "of which" or "in which". Are either correct? If not, what is?

> Strict-liability crimes are crimes **[of/in] which** the burden of proof is reversed.

Originally I had "in which" but I changed it to "of which" after rephrasing the area of concern mentally: *the burden of proof of/in crimes*.

Comment: Strict-liability crimes are crimes in the prosecution of which the burden of proof is reversed.

Comment: I would use "for which".

Comment: @Andy A-ha! I don't know how I missed that. Could you please make it an answer so I can accept it?

Comment: Wrong prepositions. You need "for": _crimes **for** which the burden of proof is reversed_.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would say

> **For** these crimes, the burden of proof is reversed.

Accordingly, I would write

> These are crimes **for** which the burden of proof is reversed.

Comment: Thank you. As I mentioned to Andy, I don't know how this slipped my mind!

Answer (score 0):

I would use neither "in which" or "of which," but rather "regarding which."  Also, I believe you are mistaken in the content of your sentence.  :)  Strict liability is not pertinent to criminal law, but rather to tort law in a civil law context.  In criminal law, there are "general intent" crimes where the actor simply has to be conscious and deliberately doing a prohibited act in order to be found guilty (such as walking onto someone's "posted no trespassing" property), and "specific intent" crimes where the prosecutor must prove that the person's intent was as specified in the statute (such as entering a building with the intent to steal therein--burglary).  Also, the burden of proof of every element of a crime is always with the prosecution in America--with proof beyond a reasonable doubt.

Comment: Actually, I'd like to respectfully disagree. Here in Victoria, if someone is found carrying a knife (which is a criminal offence) **they** must prove their innocence, thus reversing the burden/onus of proof. This is also the same for serving liquor to U18s.