# How to use "in which"

Tags: american-english

"He came by a couple of jobs in the field of journalism, **in which** he had to travel a lot between states, and so it wasn't very practical."

Do I use "in which" here, and if so, should there be a comma before it? Is there any other grammatical error in the sentence?

Comment: I would use ***for which***  he had to travel *for* his job, not in his job.

Comment: ...or possibly: "...jobs in the field of journalism which required a lot of travel between states..." (no comma)

Comment: I prefer Cascabel's rephrase, or something like *..., but they involved a lot of travel between states, so weren't very practical*. Personally I think *in* is better than *for*, and the main problem with your sentence is it comes after *field of journalism*, so we read *in the field of journalism* at first and then have to go back. *In that role, I had to travel a lot* is fine, and *job* can have the same meaning as *role*.

Answer (score 0):

Possible duplicate / combination of ["In which" or "of which"?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/315253/in-which-or-of-which) and [Comma usage before “in which”](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/445780/comma-usage-before-in-which).

From the answers in these two similar questions, I would answer your question by saying **for which** with a comma.

However there are a few other parts of the sentence that confuse me as a native speaker:

- "**He *came by* a couple of jobs**" could have a number of different meanings:

  - He physically walked past the jobs. (Not likely with this context)
  - He worked a couple of jobs over the years. (Possible but doesn't really fit)
  - He became aware of a couple of jobs (likely what you mean)
- The current sentence structure suggests that the subject is *the field of journalism* rather than the jobs themselves. (*The field of journalism* should not be the subject because it is the jobs that require travel.)
- I'm not sure if "**and so**" is technically improper grammar but it sounds very strange to me. I would just say "so"
- I'm not sure what the "*it*" in "***it* wasn't very practical**" is referring to.
- Does "*it*" refer to the field of journalism? It is strange to label an entire field of work as impractical
- Does "*it*" refer to the jobs? The jobs are plural, so the sentence should say "*they weren't* very practical."
- If this sentence were not by itself, I would assume "*it*" refers to the subject of the previous sentence.

If I were to rewrite the sentence, I would say something like:

*He found some Journalist jobs, but they were not practical because they required out-of-state travel.*

Comment: So you would rewrite the original as "He came by a couple of jobs [in the field of journalism], for which he had to travel a lot between states..."??? It is arguably a restrictive relative clause. Why would it need a comma?